# ASP.NET MVC 5 Custom Attribute Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html, asp.net-mvc-5

I am implementing an image upload option in my MVC application but I keep getting the following error: The type or namespace name 'FileSizeAttribute' could not be found.

As you can see from my code below I am implementing cusom attributes to determine the allowed file size and type.

```
public class UploadImageModel
    {
        [FileSize(10240)]
        [FileTypes("jpg,jpeg,png")]
        public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
    }
```

I define these attributes in my ProfileController.cs as you can see here.

```
public class FileSizeAttribute : ValidationAttribute
        {
            private readonly int _maxSize;

            public FileSizeAttribute(int maxSize)
            {
                _maxSize = maxSize;
            }

            public override bool IsValid(object value)
            {
                if (value == null) return true;

                return _maxSize > (value as HttpPostedFile).ContentLength;
            }
            public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
            {
                return string.Format("The image size should not exceed {0}", _maxSize);
            }
        }

        public class FileTypesAttribute : ValidateInputAttribute
        {
            private readonly List<string> _types;

            public FileTypesAttribute(string types)
            {
                _types = types.Split(',').ToList();
            }

            public override bool IsValid(object value)
            {
                if (value == null) return true;

                var fileExt = System.IO.Path.GetExtension((value as HttpPostedFile).FileName).Substring(1);
                return _types.Contains(fileExt, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
            }

            public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
            {
                return string.Format("Invalid file type. Only the following types {0} are supported.",
                    String.Join(", ", _types));
            }
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult PhotoUpload(UploadImageModel imageModel)
        {
            string path = @"D:\Temp\";

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (imageModel != null && imageModel.File != null)
                    image.SaveAs(path + imageModel.File.FileName);

                return RedirectToAction("Profile");
            }

            return View();
        }
```

I should mention that I am adapting code from this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/442515/Uploading-and-returning-files-in-ASP-NET-MVC) as I am new to MVC and just learning the ropes. That said, do I need to include a using clause in my header the references my Controller or is it a syntax issue that I am missing? Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Is the class in the same namespace as the model class? Otherwise, yes, you need to add a using directive.

Comment: @TiesonT. one is in the artisan.Models namespace and the other is in the artisan.Controllers namespace. Would this be a problem? If so what using directive should I use?

Comment: The attribute should really be in it's own file. What namespace you give it is up to you, but then you add that namespace to the model class. So, if your attribute was in `artisan.Attributes`, you would add a `using artisan.Attributes;` to the model class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume you, at a minimum, moved those attributes out into a combined file, call it `ExtensionAttributes.cs`. Inside that file, you would have something like

```
namespace artisan.Attributes
{
    public class FileSizeAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {
        private readonly int _maxSize;

        public FileSizeAttribute(int maxSize)
        {
            _maxSize = maxSize;
        }

        public override bool IsValid(object value)
        {
            if (value == null) return true;

            return _maxSize > (value as HttpPostedFile).ContentLength;
        }
        public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
        {
            return string.Format("The image size should not exceed {0}", _maxSize);
        }
    }

    public class FileTypesAttribute : ValidateInputAttribute
    {
        private readonly List<string> _types;

        public FileTypesAttribute(string types)
        {
            _types = types.Split(',').ToList();
        }

        public override bool IsValid(object value)
        {
            if (value == null) return true;

            var fileExt = System.IO.Path.GetExtension((value as HttpPostedFile).FileName).Substring(1);
            return _types.Contains(fileExt, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        }

        public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
        {
            return string.Format("Invalid file type. Only the following types {0} are supported.",
                String.Join(", ", _types));
        }
    }
}
```

Then, to use the attribute on your model, you would do something like

```
using artisan.Attributes;

public class UploadImageModel
{
    [FileSize(10240)]
    [FileTypes("jpg,jpeg,png")]
    public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
}
```

Otherwise, as-is, you need to add a `artisan.Controllers` to your model class, but that (given the default project template) might cause some circular references.